# Access denied for user 'root'@localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, phpmyadmin

I am using a piece of hardware called a Meshlium AP, which I use to estimate where people are based on smartphone pings. If I am connected to the meshlium network I can access the management panel at 10.10.10.1.

Originally, I was working on a Windows Laptop and when connected to the Meshlium network, within their Management system (located at 10.10.10.1) I have the option to go to phpMyAdmin on local host to download the SQL data.  I was able to login with the supplied username and password.  I am still able to do this easily

I am now working on a Mac and when I attempt to login phpMyAdmin through their management system, I get this error "Access denied for user 'root'@localhost' (using password: YES)".  I am using the same username and pass that still currently works on the PC

I have a feeling it might be some permission issues, but I have no idea how or what to change.

Any thoughts on how or what permissions I can change to gain access?

Comment: i get the same error with "mysql -u NAME -p PASS -h 10.10.10.1" in terminal

Comment: Sorry for late comment, do you remember how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the password is correct then it sounds like the 'host' for the user is only localhost, and not setup to allow other hosts (even on LAN) to connect.

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. where is this screen that you have shown above?

Comment: in phpMyAdmin:  Users -> (find a root one) Edit Privs -> Change Login Information / Copy User -> Change "Host" field to 'any'. You SHOULDN'T leave this as ANY, as its very insecure. Create a non-root user once you have confirmed that this was the issue.

Comment: @Jono20201, what if is under mac, Host to set what?